# How to set anchor to fit the text at center of image with PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Drawn text on an image with Pillow library, tried to fit the text anchored at center of image by option `anchor='mm'`, but it looks not exactly as center of image.

Demo code

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

im = Image.new("RGBA", (500, 500), (255, 255, 255, 255))
font = ImageFont.truetype(font='arial.ttf', size=320)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((250, 250), "123", font=font, fill='black', anchor='mm')
im.show()
```

result:

[image]

expectation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the text looks misaligned is because there is a little margin at the left of the `1` and pillow will align the text including this margin.

Adding `0` at both ends will visualize that it is correctly centered and that there is a large margin at `1`.

[image: Image with 0 on both ends]

If you want to align the text excluding margins, `ImageFont.getmask` is helpful.

```py
def get_offset_for_true_mm(text, draw, font):
    anchor_bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font=font, anchor='lt')
    anchor_center = (anchor_bbox[0] + anchor_bbox[2]) // 2, (anchor_bbox[1] + anchor_bbox[3]) // 2
    mask_bbox = font.getmask(text).getbbox()
    mask_center = (mask_bbox[0] + mask_bbox[2]) // 2, (mask_bbox[1] + mask_bbox[3]) // 2
    return anchor_center[0] - mask_center[0], anchor_center[1] - mask_center[1]


im = Image.new("RGBA", (500, 500), (255, 255, 255, 255))
font = ImageFont.truetype(font='arial.ttf', size=320)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
text = "123"
offset = get_offset_for_true_mm(text, draw, font)
draw.text((250 + offset[0], 250 + offset[1]), text, font=font, fill='black', anchor='mm')
im.show()
```

Result:

[image: Image aligned excluding margins]

Comment: I got the reason why not well center-aligned, it is based on font. Tried to use `Image.getbbox` and `Image.paste` for it, and worked. To calculate the offset should be better than the way I did, thank you !